# How do I move my partition to my primary file spot?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

VM Ubuntu 14.04, I have run out of space and I want to expand my partition. I have created additional space using VMWARE Player. I have set my ISO to be the boot, and installed GParted.

When I create a new partition it is not seen by Ubuntu. Do I have to "touch" `/dev/sda1`? or does it matter?

Does it matter if the partition is way over on the right? I can't see it in Nautilus.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Yes you have to move the other partitions so the unallocated space is adjacent to the partition you want to expand. You have to do this in several steps -> move -> apply changes -> resize -> apply changes.

Comment: You show the little key icons which mean partition is mounted/locked. You cannot edit mounted partitions. So use live installer and gparted from with in it.

Comment: you could make a partition with the unallocated space and move your home folder there also.....  PS currently you do not have a partition on the right, it is unused space (unallocated). you can make a partition there though

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have gotten all locks off of the 'Gparted' interface with the exception of '/dev/sda1' which is the farthest on the left.  I have tried to resize/move things with no luck so far.  I have had very little luck getting to where I run the machine from the iso.  Does it matter if the only 'lock' is on a partition I am not trying to modify?